# Deeplinking Ionic Application and opening it from another application

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, deep-linking

I am trying out the deeplink an application. I was able to do deeplinking using a cordova plugin. So now I have the following scenerios:-

1. When someone clicks on the URL https://sample.com, it opens up my app (Works as expected)
2. I want to use the scheme as hyperlink within another application so that it opens my app.

How to go around with the second problem. I also want to open the app if someone types the URL explicitly.

So basically the problem is invoking one app from another using the scheme URI

Comment: As far as I understand, the other app will have to open your app using your scheme. In other words, they will have to 'call' [yourscheme]://someroute. If the app opens your website, the device's browser will try to open your app if the scheme in the server matches your app's scheme.

Comment: Yes This is what I want to do. But is there server involved too. I was not aware of this part. Please guide me. @ChristianBenseler I am using Android as of now as my platform and also have to do the same for iOS

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can open another app like this.

```
navigator.app.loadUrl(link, {openExternal: true});
```